# Laravel OrderBy and Search base meta Related to Post with Pagination

Tags: laravel, database, sorting, filter, eloquent

I have a archive page. i need **sort posts base on meta's post** and **search posts base meta's post**, also result use **pagination**.

```
// App\Models\Post

public function postmetas(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Postmeta::class, 'post_id');
    }

public function laststepcompleted(): HasOne
    {
        return $this->HasOne(Postmeta::class, 'post_id')->where('name', 'step_completed')->orderByRaw('CONVERT(value, SIGNED) desc');
    }
```

i use below code for sort but it don't work (error: *laststepcompleted.id column not found*)

```
$posts = Post::with('postmetas')->with('laststepcompleted')
        ->when($this->sort == 'step_down', function ($query) {
            $query->orderByRaw('laststepcompleted.id asc');
        })->paginate(10);
```

also post has multiple meta like fullname, address, ... and i want filter (**Search**) post base if has meta that contains $search_query;

**Notic**: *sort and filter must run in db query not collection because pagination*.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are only eager loading the relationship, but if you need to query the table, then you also have to join it in. Besides that, you can also `with` multiple relations in a single call like `::with(['relation1', 'relation2'])`

And for your query, you can try something like:

```
$posts = Post::with(['postmetas', 'laststepcompleted'])
    ->join('laststepcompleted', 'laststepcompleted.post_id', '=', 'posts.id')
    ->when($this->sort == 'step_down', function ($query) {
        $query->orderByRaw('laststepcompleted.id asc');
    })->paginate(10);
```